# Import large table to azure sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to transfer one table from my SQL Server instance database to newly created database on Azure. The problem is that insert script is 60 GB large.

I know that the one approach is to create backup file and then load it into storage and then run import on azure. But the problem is that when I try to do so than while importing on azure IO have an error:

```
Could not load package.
 File contains corrupted data.
 File contains corrupted data.
```

Second problem is that using this approach I cant copy only one table, the whole database has to be in the backup file.

So is there any other way to perform such an operation? What is the best solution. And if the backup is the best then why I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tools out there that make this very easy (point and click). If it's a one time thing, you can use virtually any tool ([Red Gate](http://cloudservices.red-gate.com), [BlueSyntax](http://bluesyntax.net/backup20.aspx)...). You always have [BCP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) as well. Most of these approaches will allow you to backup or restore a single table.

If you need something more repeatable, you should consider using a [backup API](http://bluesyntax.net/Backup20API.aspx) or code this yourself using the [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I'd ever try to execute a 60gb script. Scripts generally do single inserts which aren't very optimized. Have you explored using various bulk import/export options?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx/css
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx/css

If this is a one-time load, using a IaaS VM to do the import into the SQL Azure database might be a good alternative. The data file, once exported could be compressed/zipped and uploaded to blob storage. Then pull that file back out of storage into your VM so you can operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using BCP in the command prompt?
As explained here: [Bulk Insert Azure SQL](http://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/).

You basically create a text file with all your table data in it and bulk copy it your azure sql database by using the BCP command in the command prompt.

Comment: Limitation of 1000 records at a time bites. I've got a table with 380k records.

Comment: There's no actual limit of 1k records. The code only inserts them 1k at a time.
So if you'd have 380k records it'll do 380 bulk inserts of 1k records

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see bcp *allows* specifying batch size (-b option, or -h "ROWS_PER_BATCH = bb" load hint), with motivation that "if the transaction for any batch fails, only insertions from the current batch are rolled back." Don't see in your blog or the ms doc where 1,000 is the default. In my case, I ended up with (export db) + (table data transfer w/INSERT INTO ... SELECT on localhost server w/o Azure's limitations) + (deploy back to Azure). Big table (w/a geography column), but modest-sized DB when done, less than 1GB.